# chinese character issue in file_get_contents

Tags: php, file-get-contents

i was trying very basic file get contents for chinese character and for most of the sites it works if charset is specified as utf8 but for few sites it gives something messy. here is my code and putput. any observation/suggestion is welcome

```
    <head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /></head>          <?php
          $homepage = file_get_contents('http://wallpaper.pconline.com.cn/pic/23731.html');

      echo $homepage;
           ?>
```

i have checked in phpfiddle also there also same output http://phpfiddle.org/

```
          ���R�6(A�j �rr ۖ���U�vu�n��#���SJsS6�Wk��Sd��ڸݰ��Sk��^�̩j��(F3%M(����3��;ʬ:�4ڪ�!-E��q����9��M{U���^�f���9�Z;���[o\;w��~���K��:y����>�s���˟�>u������� �_]�p����^�����S'�t��կ����e�0ˢ��fs�t����W/\������T
```

Comment: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=GBK">` - unsurprisingly the document on the site in question was not encoded as UTF-8, you can't just slap on a UTF-8 tag and hope for the best - you will have to convert it.  I'd start by looking into [`mb_convert_encoding`](http://uk1.php.net/mb_convert_encoding)

Comment: You should better find an other example website, not for office use !!!

Comment: @AxelAmthor sorryyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy